# Посчитать дни между датами с условием

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть две переменные `DATE_IN` и `END_DATE`.
Если `DATE_IN` и `END_DATE` равны, то считаем как 1 день, а если `DATE_IN` и `END_DATE` не равны, то считаем, как обычно, - количество дней между ними.

Как правильно написать `select` или функцию под эти условия?

Comment: `SELECT CASE WHEN END_DATE = DATE_IN THEN 1 ELSE END_DATE - DATE_IN END AS DATE_DIFF FROM ...` ?

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь ,то в else так вставить не получиться выплюнет ошибку. Либо я лох и мне пора в отпуск. Приеду дом  крутану этот запрос

Comment: `Практика — критерий истины` ;-)

Comment: У меня почему то , не знаю почему в голове крутилась только одна мысль ,что в else нужно вставить это select to_date(end_date) -to_date(date_in) from ... where .... and Вот хоть убей ,но мне казалось ,что так надо

Comment: все зависит от типов данных `END_DATE` и `DATE_IN` - если это строки, то конечно их сначала надо преобразовать в дату/время

Comment: Эти колонки имеет тип DATE

Comment: Спасибо ,а то я как то походу слишком глубоко капнул ,приеду попробую отпишу

Comment: Когда приедете, спросите ваших бизнес пипл, они дейтвительно считают, что разница между "сегодня" и "сегодня" должна быть один день, им может тоже пора в отпуск.

Comment: Речь идёт о поступление ребёнка и выписке его из отделения . Т.е если ребёнок поступил и выписался в этот же день ,то нужно считать это 1 день , а у нас соответсвенно считает это условие как 0 дней ,что неприемлемо. Медицина  она такая 

Comment: А если выписали на следующий день, то это тоже 1 день?

Answer (score 3):

Вот так:

```sql
with 
function getDateDiff (start_date date, end_date date) return number is
begin 
    return case when start_date = end_date then 1 else end_date - start_date end;
end;
data as (
    select date'2019-07-01' start_date, date'2019-07-01' end_date from dual union all
    select date'2019-07-01' start_date, date'2019-07-02' end_date from dual union all
    select date'2019-07-01' start_date, date'2019-07-03' end_date from dual
)
select start_date, end_date, getDateDiff (start_date, end_date) diff 
from data
/

START_DATE          END_DATE                  DIFF
------------------- ------------------- ----------
2019-07-01 00:00:00 2019-07-01 00:00:00          1
2019-07-01 00:00:00 2019-07-02 00:00:00          1
2019-07-01 00:00:00 2019-07-03 00:00:00          2
```

Объявите функцию `getDateDiff()` в пакете или как *SQL standalone function*, если её надо использовать в *PL/SQL* контексте.